# How to join two tables in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I want to update them together. Do I have to use join?

```
UPDATE tb_empgroc_master SET total_items='$total_items', total_amount='$total_amount' WHERE empgrocmstID='$empgrocmstID';

UPDATE tb_empgrocery SET qty_ordered='$qty_ordered', amount='$amount' WHERE empgrocID='$empgrocID';
```

These two tables have the same field which is `order_no`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to update them together?

Comment: because if I deleted rows in `tb_empgrocery` or modify it's values. `tb_empgroc_master` must update and sum or count rows from the `tb_empgrocery` @rghome

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update tb_empgroc_master
JOIN tb_empgrocery on tb_empgroc_master.order_no = tb_empgrocery.order_no
set tb_empgroc_master.total_items='$total_items', 
    tb_empgroc_master.total_amount='$total_amount',
    tb_empgrocery.qty_ordered='$qty_ordered', 
    tb_empgrocery.amount='$amount'
where tb_empgroc_master.empgrocmstID='$empgrocmstID'
OR tb_empgrocery.empgrocID='$empgrocID'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update tb_empgroc_master t1, tb_empgrocery t2 
set t1.total_items='$total_items', t1.total_items='$total_amount', 
    t2.qty_ordered='$qty_ordered', t2.amount='$amount'
where t1.order_no = t2.order_no;